# How to prevent URLs that lead to a 301 redirect to show up in browser history?

Tags: php, url, redirect, paypal, http-status-code-301

Using the PayPal API, when the user cancels the process or is redirected back to the shopping cart page in order to review the order, the page URL includes the GET paramenter "token". I don't want the user to see that token, so I redirect the page to itself without the query string, using a 301 redirect. Hovewer, the URL including the token is saved in the browser history (at least in Firefox and Chrome) and shows up as autocomplete option when typing in the address bar.

The PayPal express checkout API doesn't have a parameter to make the return requests POST instead of GET (as opposed to the form-based method with hidden fields). Is there any way to do a redirect that won't have the original URL saved in the browser history?

I also tried 302 and `Refresh: 0; url=...` - but that still saves the URL...

Comment: Can you elaborate please on what token that is and why you don't want the user to see it? I'm not too familiar with the PayPal API but I doubt tihs is a security issue...

Comment: The reason I don't want the parameter to be visible to the user is that the token is a reference to the PayPal payment process, and I don't want the user to fiddle around with it in order to do something nasty. ;-) (I will add security measurements on the server-side of course, to prevent anything bad happening with those tokens! But who knows...) Plus, I don't really like ugly GET query strings. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done because the browser is seeing it as a unique URL and recording it to be helpful to the user. It's important for the browser to know the history, but I understand why you don't need to show this to the user.

If you weren't using the PayPal API, I'd suggest not using querytring values in the URL, but that's probably unavoidable in this case.

Sorry to say, but I think you're stuck with it.  I never found a way around this in any PHP or Classic ASP applications.

Comment: That's bad news... :( I cannot understand why PayPal offers the "rm" variable (which, set to a value of 2, will force the return requests to be POST instead of GET) in the basic form-based API, but not with ExpressCheckout. It's a shame!

Comment: Is using another payment gateway an alternative? There are a number of them out there that have FAR more flexibility (and lower rates) than PayPal.